# Stash changes during conflict resolution

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I am rebasing a complex feature to another branch using `git cherry-pick`. When trying to resolve conflicts in a big commit, I find out that I've missed some other commit that should be applied first.

I can't `stash` the current state, apply the other commit and then do `stash pop`.
I could do `cherry-pick --abort`, apply the other commit and then cherry-pick it again, but I would lose those resolved conflicts.

What is the best way to deal with such situation?

Comment: Is it "should be" or "must be"? If the former, continue, then rectify the situation when you have committed the resolution.

Comment: The missed commit already deals with some of the conflicts, I wouldn't have to deal with them manually.

Comment: I've done big conflicting merges in the past, and in the same situation as you describe. I bit the bullet and complete the merge. Then rewound, applied the helpful other commit, then redid the merge. Fortunately, the `rerere` machinery resolves many of the commits again automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Following [j6t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6868543/j6t) [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162960/stash-changes-during-conflict-resolution/44471764#comment69657307_41162960), you can complete then rewind, apply the other commits and cherry-pick again.

The idea is to make sure [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) is active in order to avoid resolving the merge conflicts all over again.

If you did not activated `rerere`, you have the [rerere-train.sh script I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40822408/6309), in order to not forget your conflict resolution of your first round of merges.